# firebase-admin createCustomToken does not exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

i'm trying to create a custom token for firebase in mi server

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

var serviceAccount = require('PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS');

console.log(serviceAccount);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://URL.firebaseio.com"
});

admin.auth().createCustomToken("some-uid").then(function(customToken){
       console.log(customToken);
   }
```

I follow all the steps in the documentation
1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

But i am getting an error: Property 'createCustomToken' does not exist

[image]

what can i do?